# Sort location results according to the distance Google place API

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an android app and want to implement checkIn feature in my android application.

I am using Google Places API for searching the nearby locations from the current location. I want the sorted results according to the locations, like If any location which is near I want that location to be shown first than other locations which are away.

I have  searched a lot on this and checked the link 
[Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) 
I found the rankby parameter to be send in order to find the locations in ascending order by their distance from the current location.
So, we can pass the parameter with rankby=distance.

But we need to send some of the parameters from keyword, name or type. But I want to get all the results which are nearby to the current location. I cannot send any of these parameters, so how can I do it then. Please help if anyone know about it.

Comment: The parameters you are talking about are optional parameters and need not be sent.

Comment: do you have latlong of destination ? do you have latlong of places you want to sort ?

Comment: But If I send the parameter rankby=distance to get the results in ascending order of the distance, I need to send any of these parameters (keyword, name or type) which I do not want to send because I want all nearby places.
And If I do not send rankBy parameter, it will not return the results in ascending order of distance.
Please help if you know how to get the **all nearby places in ascending order of distance from current location**, so that I can implement the same.